# Using Array.Copy function to input into procedure

Tags: vb.net

I have created a form that saves a collection of random numbers to an array. However, I would like to create an instance of the array using the array.copy function. I would also like to sort copies of the array using the Bubble sort, shell sort, array.sort function. Currently, I have been able to create the bubble sort method in a seperate sub procedure and created a copy of the array. This sub procedure is called after a "Bubble sort button" is called. The copy of the array is passed from the button to the sub procedure and the array is sorted and output to a listbox.

I  have included a copy of my source code below;

```
   Public Class Form1
    Dim randGen As New Random()
    Dim unstArray() As Integer
    Dim unstArrayCopy() As Integer
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 'Generates random number to save in array.
        Dim i As Integer = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
        ReDim unstArray(i)
        Dim x As Integer = 0
        ReDim unstArrayCopy(i)
        For x = x + 1 To i
            unstArray(x) = randGen.Next(1, 10001)
        Next
        Array.Copy(unstArray, unstArrayCopy, i)
    End Sub
    Private Sub BbleSortBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bbleSortBtn.Click
        bubbleSortProcedure(unstArrayCopy)
    End Sub
    Sub bubbleSortProcedure(bbleSrtArr() As Integer)
        Dim iTemp As Integer
        For iPass = 1 To bbleSrtArr.Length - 1
            For i = 0 To bbleSrtArr.Length - 2
                If bbleSrtArr(i) > bbleSrtArr(i + 1) Then
                    iTemp = bbleSrtArr(i)
                    bbleSrtArr(i) = bbleSrtArr(i + 1)
                    bbleSrtArr(i + 1) = iTemp
                End If
            Next i
        Next iPass
        For j = 0 + 1 To UBound(bbleSrtArr)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(bbleSrtArr(j))
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

Comment: You probably want to create a copy of the original array before passing it to the different algorithms for sorting, not in the `Button1_Click` handler. So, keep `unstArray` as a Field, make a copy in `BbleSortBtn_Click` and pass the copy to the method.

Comment: I tried creating a copy however kept receiving an error.

Comment: Maybe because you forgot to create the array and it's null? You can create a new array with `unstArrayCopy = New Integer(i) {}` in your `Button1_Click` (note that collections in .Net are indexed starting from `0`, not `1`). But, as already mentioned, you should (most) probably generate a copy of an original array before passing it to one of the methods that sorts it. Otherwise, you'll be sorting a sorted array after the first method is run.

Comment: Would I create a copy of the original array in the Button1_Click? @Jimi

Comment: I think I've already mentioned this in those two other comments.

Comment: Have declared the original array as an empty array however I have resized the array after the user inputs the size. Also, the Array.Copy function works properly, thank you! I would like advice on calling the "bubbleSortProcedure" sub in the "BbleSortBtn_Click" sub. @Jimi